# Using C#, fire event when database changes occur on MySql Server

Tags: c#, mysql, events

Without getting into too much details - I would like to be able to be notified whenever **ANY** changes occur in my MySql Database and react to this event with an event handler in my C# application.

Just as one have classes like My `MySqlConnection` or `MySqlCommand` etc, is there an class that I can create within which is contained a event that I can couple a event handler to, to be able to listen for database changes.

All I need is a very simple implementation of the above mentioned scenario, I only want to know whenever a change occurs on the database.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: It's not really a question of whether or not a .NET class exists for this purpose, but rather a question of whether or not MySQL has functionality to publish events in the first place.  I could be mistaken, but I don't think it does.  You may need to assign triggers to the tables for this, and within those triggers push some external event (such as invoking a socket operation, if MySQL has capabilities for that).

Comment: Exactly. This is a "give me classes, i dont care that the server does not provide this functionality" type of question that clearly shows the OP is in need to actually understand the tools he is using (in this case MySql).

Comment: To the OP - that sadly is a little more complex. I suggest you fork the MySql code. As you say it is simple, it won't take you long to code this functionality into MySql to start.

Answer (score 1):

To your statement:

> Just as one have classes like My MySqlConnection or MySqlCommand etc,
>   is there an class that I can create within which is contained a event
>   that I can couple a event handler to, to be able to listen for
>   database changes.

That is not possible.

What you can do is write your own `DataAccessLayer` and note all changes which are made. There is no other soltuion. If you are working with triggers and so on, it will be much more dificult, because you don't get all changes.

Maybe you can solve your provlem with another solution that getting all changes from the database. Try to think from "the other side".

Comment: I have had limited experience with MySql Databases, so to be honest i have little to no idea how implement what you have suggested.

Comment: If you use my solution, you need to know more about ADO.Net than about MySQL. Also read a lot about DAL, than you will get an idea.